# Clipping plots to other plots in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm plotting a convex frame as shown below, with the given MWE. Inside this frame, the idea is to plot additional functions to create an image. In order to avoid manually computing the domain restrictions for every function within the frame, it would be nice to simply clip (or in some other way restrict) these functions to my custom frame. (In the example below, this means that the dotted curve is not supposed to exceed the frame.) Does anyone know of a clever way to do this?

As you can see, I've tried using intersections, but I couldn't find a good solution. I've left the name definitions in the MWE in case you find them useful.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar,intersections}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{polaraxis}[samples=50,smooth,thick,axis lines=none]

% frame
\addplot[domain=45:135]{(4/sin(x))/(1+0.01*(4/sin(x))^2)};
\addplot[domain=225:315]{(-4/sin(x))/(1+0.01*(-4/sin(x))^2)};
\addplot[domain=-45:45]{(4/cos(x))/(1+0.01*(4/cos(x))^2)};
\addplot[domain=135:225]{(-4/cos(x))/(1+0.01*(-4/cos(x))^2)};

% image plot example
\addplot[dotted,domain=30:150]{(3/sin(x))/(1+0.01*(3/sin(x))^2)};

\end{polaraxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Edit: I forgot to actually square the last term in the fraction, and it turns out this introduces a problem to Fritz's otherwise great solution. When the correct functions are used in Fritz's example, the paths are completely ignored, presumably because `tikz` can't handle the mathematical expressions. They work just fine as plots in `pgfplots`, however. Are there other solutions that don't have this problem?

Sorry for the mistake! Please excuse my absent-mindedness.

Comment: It is much easier to clip this in the TikZ part of the picture. Is there any cartesian expression for the clipping part? By the way squaring is no problem so it should handled that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of drawing the frame using `\addplot`, you can create a TikZ path which describes the same shape using the `plot` and `--plot` operations. This allows you to use the `clip` key to restrict all drawing inside the current scope to the area described by the path. In order to use the TikZ `plot` operation with PGFPlots coordinates, you need to use the `axis cs` coordinate system.

When the scope ends, so does the clipping, as shown by the red path:

[image: Clipped plots]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar,intersections}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[samples=50,smooth,thick,axis lines=none]

\begin{scope} % Everything inside this scope is clipped
% frame
\path[clip,draw]
    plot[domain=44.9:135] (axis cs: \x, {(4/sin(\x))/(1+0.2*(4/sin(\x)))})
    --plot[domain=135:225] (axis cs: \x, {(-4/cos(\x))/(1+0.2*(-4/cos(\x)))})
    --plot[domain=225:315] (axis cs: \x, {(-4/sin(\x))/(1+0.2*(-4/sin(\x)))})
    --plot[domain=-45:45] (axis cs: \x, {(4/cos(\x))/(1+0.2*(4/cos(\x)))})
    --cycle;

% Clipped plot:
\addplot[dotted,domain=30:150]{(3/sin(x))/(1+0.2*(3/sin(x)))};
\end{scope}

% Scope ended, so this is not clipped:
\addplot[red,dotted,domain=20:160]{(2/sin(x))/(1+0.2*(2/sin(x)))};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

It also works when you square the second part of the quotients:

[image: With squared quotients]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar,intersections}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[samples=50,smooth,thick,axis lines=none]

\begin{scope} % Everything inside this scope is clipped
% frame
\path[clip,draw]
    plot[domain=44.9:135] (axis cs: \x, {(4/sin(\x))/(1+0.01*(4/sin(\x))^2)})
    --plot[domain=135:225] (axis cs: \x, {(-4/cos(\x))/(1+0.01*(-4/cos(\x))^2)})
    --plot[domain=225:315] (axis cs: \x, {(-4/sin(\x))/(1+0.01*(-4/sin(\x))^2)})
    --plot[domain=-45:45] (axis cs: \x, {(4/cos(\x))/(1+0.01*(4/cos(\x))^2)})
    --cycle;

% Clipped plot:
\addplot[dotted,domain=30:150]{(3/sin(x))/(1+0.01*(3/sin(x))^2)};
\end{scope}

% Scope ended, so this is not clipped:
\addplot[red,dotted,domain=20:160]{(2/sin(x))/(1+0.01*(2/sin(x))^2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for being so absent-minded, but I forgot to actually square the last term in the functions in my example. The correct functions don't seem to work with your solution, presumably because `tikz` can't handle the mathematical computations. Please excuse my silliness. Your solution is otherwise a great one. I have corrected the question.

Comment: I guess you simply forgot updating some of the equations when you added the squaring, especially the factor you changed from `0.2` to `0.01` in your question. As you can see in my updated answer and the image it produces, it actually works.

Comment: When the last terms in the fractions are squared, a different scaling coefficient is needed to get the same visual impression. I first squared all the appropriate terms without changing the scaling coefficient, and everything was plotted as expected. However, when I changed the scaling coefficients, the paths were no longer drawn. I plotted the functions elsewhere to double-check that there was, indeed, nothing weird about them. When I changed the scaling coefficient back, the paths were plotted again. The `\addplot` command didn't have this problem.

Comment: I don't know what the issue was, and I have trouble accepting that this was within my control. When I found that the `\path` command didn't work for the scaling coefficient I wanted, I plotted the frame with the `\addplot` command instead. I copied the expressions from the `\path` command and only changed `\x` to `x`. I'm looking at that file now, and the expressions are exactly the same as in your updated example. Nevertheless, your updated example plots everything very nicely. I guess I'll never know what caused this second issue. Thanks for looking into my problem and for a neat solution.