# Creating a cliping path using pgfplots' \addplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have been trying to reproduce the following example

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.polar,intersections}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{polaraxis}[samples=50,smooth,thick,axis lines=none]

\begin{scope} % Everything inside this scope is clipped
% frame
\path[clip,draw]
    plot[domain=44.9:135] (axis cs: \x, {(4/sin(\x))/(1+0.01*(4/sin(\x))^2)})
    --plot[domain=135:225] (axis cs: \x, {(-4/cos(\x))/(1+0.01*(-4/cos(\x))^2)})
    --plot[domain=225:315] (axis cs: \x, {(-4/sin(\x))/(1+0.01*(-4/sin(\x))^2)})
    --plot[domain=-45:45] (axis cs: \x, {(4/cos(\x))/(1+0.01*(4/cos(\x))^2)})
    --cycle;

% Clipped plot:
\addplot[dotted,domain=30:150]{(3/sin(x))/(1+0.01*(3/sin(x))^2)};
\end{scope}

% Scope ended, so this is not clipped:
\addplot[red,dotted,domain=20:160]{(2/sin(x))/(1+0.01*(2/sin(x))^2)};
\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202058/clipping-plots-to-other-plots-in-pgfplots/202062#202062). Unfortunately, the region I want to create involves functions that can't be properly plotted using tikz's plotting capability. I can plot them using pgfplots' \addplot, but I have no idea how to extract a path and join them to other points and paths.
My overall aim is to plot a contour filled region (also from pgfplot). I would appreciate any direction or help.

Edit: I want to connect the point (-0.66,2) to the path

```
\addplot[domain=-0.66:0, clip = true] {-2*x*(x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))};
```

this path to

```
\addplot[domain=0:2] {2*x*(-x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))};
```

then, this path to (2,2) and cycle to (-0.66,2) and then use this region within a scope to clip a contour filled.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! So, how does the path you wish to use as clipping path look like? Please provide the path as `\addplot` construct if this is the only way you get it working.

Comment: Thanks! sure, I want to connect the point (-0.66,2) to the path
\addplot[domain=-0.66:0, clip = true] {-2*x*(x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))} this path to  \addplot[domain=0:2] {2*x*(-x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))} then, this path to (2,2) and cycle to (-0.66,2) and then use this region within a scope to clip a contour filled.

Comment: Maybe add this to your question? Use the Edit link.

Comment: Added! thanks in advance... maybe this is trivial but Ive spent a couple of hours looking at how to do this before I decided to ask the experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is not so much of a problem and Ti*k*Z is totally capable of plotting these functions.

There is only one thing you need to take care of: Due to some mysterious mechanisms, you need to wrap `\x` in parentheses if you want it to take negative values that are to be exponentiated. So, you should write `(\x)^2` instead of `\x^2` if `\x` may be negative. But this only holds for the `plot` functions in Ti*k*Z.

You probably don't want polar axes, I guess:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=100, smooth, axis lines=none]

\begin{scope} 
\path[clip]
    (-0.66,2) -- 
    plot[domain=-0.66:0] (axis cs: \x, {-2*\x*((\x)^2 + sqrt(1+(\x)^4))}) -- 
    plot[domain=0:2] (axis cs: \x, {2*\x*(-\x^2 + sqrt(1+\x^4))}) -- 
    (2,2) -- cycle;
\fill[red] (-1,5) rectangle (10,-10);
\end{scope}

\addplot[domain=-0.66:0] {-2*x*(x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))};
\addplot[domain=0:2] {2*x*(-x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))}; 

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Another way would be to use the `fillbetween` library. This way, you don't need to plot everything twice.

Since the two paths don't really intersect (only in one point, which can be easily missed by Ti*k*Z due to rounding errors), we should use the whole paths in the sequence definition using `L*` and `R*` and not intersection segments:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=100, smooth, axis lines=none]

\addplot[domain=-0.66:0, name path=A] {-2*x*(x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))};
\addplot[domain=0:2, name path=B] {2*x*(-x^2 + sqrt(1+ x^4))}; 

\begin{scope} 
\path[clip, intersection segments={of=A and B, 
    sequence={L* -- R*}}] -- (2,2) -- (-0.66,2) -- cycle;
\fill[red] (-1,5) rectangle (10,-10);
\end{scope}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output looks the same as above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer... just as a note for future reference, I just tested and it also works if you replace (\x^2) with pow(\x,2)... such a weird little 'bug'. Just one more question, would this be possible using pgfplots' \addplot?

Comment: Well, it would be a bit more complicated, but it could probably be done in a similar manner as [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665423/47927).

Comment: @NoobNoob Correction: it can be done, as long as the paths you want to combine intersect. See my edit.

Comment: @NoobNoob Correction 2: The paths only intersect in one point and Ti*k*Z has sometimes problems to identify such things due to rounding errors. But we still can use this approach and just define the sequence in such a way that the whole paths are selected.